# wamp mysql user with password

Tags: mysql, wamp

hey guys i have installed wamp server with mysql and i have one user root without password. but now i want create one another user with password. when i was create user with password and check his connection with mysql_connect() its give me error like this

```
 Access denied for user 'Dest'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

### But password is realy correct. what can i do? i was delete this user and create other user but i have the same problem. if anyone knows that problem please help me

Hey Guys Problem Has Been Solved. Problem was that when i was create user i was choose % this local and global hosts but for wamp global accses for sql base is disabled with defoult and i think poblem is that. when i create user with Localhost its worked fine. thanks all for help :)

Comment: restart the wamp after adding a user

Comment: show the Create Statement for the user. Did you do it via the cli or some tool?  Did you grant the user access/privs to any databases?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to connect as root and get the above error, it means that you do not have a row in the user table with a User column value of 'root' and that mysqld cannot resolve the host name for your client:

from the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

for more information 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset